# What to do if RWekajars package installation gets stuck on Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS?

Tags: r, linux, installation, package, rjava

I am trying to install the RWekajars package on Linux Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, but the installation is getting stuck at the moment described below. It seems to be processing something, but it does not display an error. I have already successfully installed rJava, as well as several other packages. How can I solve this problem? I need to install the package, but it is not progressing.

I have already successfully run the command "R CMD javareconf"

What could be happening?

```
> install.packages("RWekajars", dependencies = TRUE, type = "source")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/RWekajars_3.9.3-2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 10030557 bytes (9.6 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 9.6 MB

* installing *source* package ‘RWekajars’ ...
** package ‘RWekajars’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
No man pages found in package  ‘RWekajars’ 
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
**** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location**
```

At this point, it gets stuck for hours, nothing happens....

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 Patched (2022-11-10 r83330)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.10.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.10.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2  tools_4.2.2     rstudioapi_0.14
```

Comment: `install.packages("RWekajars")` works fine for me, 22.04.2 LTS user, cheers!

Comment: I really don't know what to do about the problem. I've never seen this before and I don't know how I can investigate why.

Comment: Did you try the reduced code?

Comment: How could I do this?

Comment: Are you kidding? See my first comment, please.

Comment: Sorry. I thought it was something else. I already did that, I already put the command like this: `install.packages("RWekajars")`

The problem remains the same, it is stuck and does not give any error. All other things work normally.

Comment: Thanks. Start a fresh R session run `sessionInfo()` and paste as [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75989943/edit) in your question, please.

Comment: Ok, I added the sessionInfo().

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall rJava - I had the same issue and reinstalling from rforge solved it for me

```
R -e "install.packages('rJava', repos='https://rforge.net')"
R CMD javareconf
R -e "install.packages('RWeka', type = 'source')"
```